# I/O errors and undeletable directories

Tags: io, inode, corruption, delete

For some unknown reason, there are 2 directories I can't delete.

First directory called **sw.old** is empty and can be deleted only by `rm`, as `rmdir` won't recognize it. However, even after `rm`, it still shows up:

```
[02:11:36] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs$ ls -il
total 1072064
1456 drwx------ 1 user user          0 Aug 12 10:04 1old.or.probably.unfinished
5717 drwx------ 1 user user       8192 Jan 27 22:58 videos
6528 -rw------- 1 user user 1097779088 Nov  5 16:15 release_Remix_OS_for_PC_Android_M_64bit_B2016112101.zip
8008 drwx------ 1 user user       4096 Jan 28 00:55 txt
  64 drwx------ 1 user user          0 Dec 25 22:15 sw.old
[02:12:03] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs$ rmdir sw.old/
rmdir: failed to remove ‘sw.old/’: No such file or directory
[02:12:57] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs$ rm -rf sw.old/
[02:13:15] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs$ ls -il
total 1072064
1456 drwx------ 1 user user          0 Aug 12 10:04 1old.or.probably.unfinished
5717 drwx------ 1 user user       8192 Jan 27 22:58 videos
6528 -rw------- 1 user user 1097779088 Nov  5 16:15 release_Remix_OS_for_PC_Android_M_64bit_B2016112101.zip
8008 drwx------ 1 user user       4096 Jan 28 00:55 txt
  64 drwx------ 1 user user          0 Dec 25 22:15 sw.old
```

Second one called **misc** has a corrupted file inside it:

```
[02:24:32] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs/txt$ ls -il
total 0
22607 drwx------ 1 user user 0 Dec 31 16:09 misc
[02:24:36] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs/txt$ ls -il misc/
ls: cannot access misc/patterns.mp4: Input/output error
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? patterns.mp4
[02:24:54] user@user:/media/user/exthdd/docs/txt$ rm -rf misc/
rm: cannot remove ‘misc/patterns.mp4’: Input/output error
```

How can I remove those directories (and corrupted file inside one of them) without formatting?

Comment: Bear in mind that `-f` tells `rm` not to issue *any* error messages. So the lack of output from `rm -rf sw.old/` doesn’t mean that it worked; it just means that it failed silently. Maybe there are invisible characters in the name. What does `ls -ilb` say? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … OTOH, a directory should never have size 0, so you’ve probably got a corrupt filesystem.

Comment: `ls -ilb` gives the same output, so I guess that won't be problem. Regarding corrupt filesystem, everything else on disk works fine, is there a chance there will be more problems like this if I don't format?

Comment: You should unmount your disk and do a `fsck` as there seems to be something wrong with the filesystem. Also check the health of your disk.

Answer (score 0):

I've only had that error message show up when there's been a problem accessing the drive itself. Given that it appears to be an external drive, I'd check the cable, interface, cable connections, and drive: if any of those aren't working properly, you'll get those errors.

Until you check the drive and run `fsck` on the filesystem, I'd recommend against trying anything further.

Comment: And take an extra backup first, at least if the disk contains anything important. Sometimes `fsck` can fix things; other times it just manages to make some hidden filesystem corruption clearly apparent, leaving a mess for the sysadmin to clean up. If that happens, it is very nice to have the "nuclear option" of just running `mkfs` and restoring a backup.

Comment: @ErikF that's the weirdest thing because except those 2 "bedrock" directories, disk works very well and there are no any other problems with it

Comment: @telcoM right now I don't have enough time and storage to make an backup

Comment: Does `dmesg` show any kernel errors?

Comment: @ErikF nope, no logs after trying to remove both of them

Answer (score 0):

You can check what's writing to that location or file with `lsof`.  For example:

`lsof /media/user/exthdd/docs/`

or even:

`lsof / |grep sw.old`

Additionally, you can create a backup on a separate disk or archive and try to fix the underlying filesystem if there is corruption.  However, that depends on the filesystem type and/or storage setup you have in place.

Comment: `lsof` gives no output (so nothing is writing). And I can't do backup right now, that's why I'm trying do to it without wiping the whole drive